# Distance between rows ListView Android

Tags: java, android, xml, listview

I'd like to create a ListView which contains an ImageView and a TextView in every row. I am able to do that but I have a problem with changing the distance between the rows. I think somehow I changed it but I don't know how.

ActorAdapter.java:

```
ArrayList<Actors> actorList;
LayoutInflater vi;
int Resource;
ViewHolder holder;

public ActorAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Actors> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    vi = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    Resource = resource;
    actorList = objects;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // convert view = design
    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        v = vi.inflate(Resource, null);
        holder.image= (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.miniimage);
        holder.name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
        holder.image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("megnyomtam","a fost");
            }
        });
        holder.name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("megnyomtam","a fost");
            }
        });
        v.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
    }
    holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    new DownloadImageTask(holder.image).execute(actorList.get(position).getImageurl());
    holder.name.setText(actorList.get(position).getTitle());
    return v;

}

static class ViewHolder {
    public ImageView image;
    public TextView name;

}

private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView bmImage;

    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon11;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    }

}
```

ActorFragment.java

```
ArrayList<Actors> actorsList;
ActorAdapter adapter;
ListView listview;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_actor,parent, false);
    actorsList = new ArrayList<Actors>();
    new JSONAsyncTask().execute("http://demo.breona.hu:8080/mobil/mobilService?method=getAllData&appid=ESK");

    listview = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.list25);
    adapter = new ActorAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.listview_row_layout, actorsList);

    listview.setAdapter(adapter);

    return v;
}
```

The problem is maybe hiding in the xmls so I copy that too.

listview_row_layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:background="@drawable/background">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/rellayout">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:id="@+id/miniimage"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:onClick="onClick"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/miniimage"
        android:text="Cherry"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:onClick="onClick"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

activity_actor.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"    android:background="#F1F1F1"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list25"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:listitem="@layout/listview_row_layout">

</ListView>
```

Here is a picture of what I'd like to see: 
https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/customizing-android-listview-rows-subclassing‌​/

Comment: try to change height of listview_row_layout.xml or use recyclerView and add a custom devider.

Comment: Can you post an image of what you want

Comment: How? Programatically or in the xml? And what should I change in listview_row_layout.xml?

Comment: @VivekMishra  `https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/customizing-android-listview-rows-subclassing/` I'd just like a simple listview. Every item is right below from each other.

Comment: @J.Doe your url shows page not found. And add it in your question instead of comment

Comment: The URL page is good. It loads the pictures and the texts it's just far from each other. There is a big space between two items.

Comment: android:divider="#0000"
  android:dividerHeight="25dp"   // add these tags on your listview in xml

Comment: @VivekKhare Unfortunately it's the same. Just a 25dp thick line shows up in the bottom of every item.

Comment: android:divider="#0000" have you added this tag //this will make those lines transparent else you can just add margin to your listview items

Answer (score 0):

In order to change the distance between rows you can use padding/margin on your LinearLayout that contains the id - rellayout.
(in your listview_row_layout.xml)

or you could create a view element to push spaces above/below that layout..
like

```
//for example 10dp height
<View android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="10dp"
      android:layout_below="@+id/rellayout"/>
```

you can give that view a color too if you want etc..

personally I would got for padding/margins on the main layout instead of creating more views to draw, but that's another way to achieve your goal, and I don't know exactly what you are doing and what's the best method for you.

Comment: Unfortunately not working. Maybe the mistake is not in the xml files?

Comment: impossible, you're telling me that you add a view and you don't see the space??

Answer (score 0):

```
<ListView
android:id="@+id/list"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:divider="@color/yourColor"
android:dividerHeight="distnace in dp">
```